# Complicated ActiveRecord query with relationships and enumerables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I am trying to build a scope for my Model, but I am not very good doing queries when there are relationships in the middle.

How could I query all the `Books` that do not have any `Request` with the status `:completed`?

**Book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base

    # Relationships
    has_many :requests, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Request.rb**

```
class Request < ActiveRecord::Base
    # Relationships
    belongs_to :book

    # Enumerables
    enum status: [:pending, :accepted, :completed]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
Book.includes(:requests)
  .where("requests.status <> 'completed' OR requests.id IS NULL")
```

`includes` makes a `LEFT JOIN` with the `requests` table. Then you query with pure `SQL` for books with no requests or books that requests are not completed.

Comment: @Dbugger Ops, my bad. The status is on the requests table, i'll edit.

Comment: Check the server log to see the `SQL` query generated. Check if it matches your purpose. The query as is, should retrieve all books with requests with status different from completed.

Comment: Maybe the enum mapped the symbol to the string. In the database it is `"completed"`

Comment: I just realized one thing. This query excludes the books with NO requests at all... How can I fix that?

Comment: Well, when you do a `includes`, automatically `AR` do a `LEFT JOIN`, so you have all your records, even the ones without `requests`. But when you query for `WHERE status != completed`, it excludes all of the records without status, so you could add a check for `OR requests.id IS NULL`.

Comment: I got this error: `SQLException: no such column: requests.status: SELECT  "books".* FROM "books" WHERE (requests.status <> 'completed' OR requests.id IS NULL) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
`